# Eager execution in tensorflow probability stops recording gradients at second iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, eager-execution

Somehow I don't get gradients in my train loop. Below is a simple example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tf.enable_eager_execution()

hidden_size = 32
output_size = 1
m = tf.keras.Sequential(
[
            tfp.layers.DenseLocalReparameterization(hidden_size, tf.nn.leaky_relu),
            tfp.layers.DenseLocalReparameterization(hidden_size, tf.nn.leaky_relu),
            tfp.layers.DenseLocalReparameterization(output_size)
        ]
)
```

If I run a gradient recording step two times, the second times doesn't show any gradients. A list with `None` types is returned.

```
for _ in range(2):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_value = m(tf.ones((1, 2))) * 2
        print(tape.gradient(loss_value, m.trainable_variables))
```

This is not the case if we replace the model `m` by a 'standard' tensorflow model, i.e.

`m = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])`

I am using tensorflow=1.13.1 and tensorflow-probability=0.6.0

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a temporary bug. I uploaded to the nightly releases of tensorflow and tensorflow probability and the problem is solved.

Comment: We just fixed some issues around TF2 gradients in these layer classes yesterday, so it's possible your most recent update caught those fixes. Let us know if you have any more problems! (Feel free to file issues on our issue tracker on github -- https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). Cheers!